# Dynamic data on custom shapes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I want to build an application where for one of my designs I would like to populate shapes with dynamic data. These will be custom shapes where I have two different shapes and they alternate one below the other. So I have a left shape and then the next one will be a right shape and so on. Is is possible to create this in Flutter and how would I do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture or a short clip of what you want to do?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I've just updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Is the overlay important?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I would prefer it with the overlay

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi Thank you, I didn't think it would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. I have simplify the shape with my custom triangle shape created with `CustomPainter` so you will have to modify it to your needs.

```
ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        OverflowTitle(color: Colors.green),
        OverflowTitle(color: Colors.blue),
        OverflowTitle(color: Colors.red)
      ],
    );
```

and custom overflow title

```
class OverflowTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  const OverflowTitle({this.color});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 50,
      child: OverflowBox(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        minHeight: 50,
        maxHeight: 70,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TrianglePainter(
              strokeColor: color,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'NO1',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is output

[image]

Let me know if you need more help with it...

UPDATE
here is my custom triangle painter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }

class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  final Direction direction;

  TrianglePainter({this.strokeColor = Colors.white, this.direction});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path getTrianglePath(double x, double y) {
    if (direction == Direction.Right) {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(0, y)
        ..lineTo(x, y / 2)
        ..lineTo(0, 0)
        ..lineTo(0, y);
    } else if (direction == Direction.Left) {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(x, 0)
        ..lineTo(0, y / 2)
        ..lineTo(x, y)
        ..lineTo(x, 0);
    } else if (direction == Direction.Down) {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(0, 0)
        ..lineTo(x / 2, y)
        ..lineTo(x, 0)
        ..lineTo(0, 0);
    } else {
      return Path()
        ..moveTo(0, y)
        ..lineTo(x / 2, 0)
        ..lineTo(x, y)
        ..lineTo(0, y);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TrianglePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.strokeColor != strokeColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Check updated answer.. I have added my custom trianglepainter class.. You will have to modify it to your shape